# Game Refresh on Javascript Canvas Issue glitchy/flashing, using SetInterval

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval, requestanimationframe, game-loop

Need help with Canvas refresh, very glitchy and flashing, and im using setInterval. Dont know how to use requestanimation frame, any help is great

//initiates entire game

```
function fullLoader() {     

    setInterval(drawPoke, fps);
    setInterval(drawHaunt, fps);
    setInterval(drawChar, fps);
    setInterval(drawDusk, fps);
    setInterval(refresh, 1000/30);
}

function refresh() {

    con.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
```

The function are drawings or png images and are set to relaod at the interval of fps which is set to 30.

Comment: SetInterval only executes the functions with a best effort with regards to the every_ms argument. This might mean that your functions are called in different orders. Consider placing all the rendering tasks in one function in the order you need them to render in and call that via setInterval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Never**..ever.. use `setInterval` for animation!

Use `requestAnimationFrame` as it is synced to the display rate and ensures that changes you make to the DOM (canvas) do not get moved to the display until the display hardware is in between frames.

```js
function fullLoader() {     
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // get first frame
}

// This mainLoop is called every 1/60th second (if you return in under 1/60th second
// if the render time is loonger than 1/60 then you will have to use
// time to keep the speed at 1/30th second. Search SO for how.
function mainLoop(time){  // time is given by browser, in ms 1/1000 
                          // accurate to 1/1,000,000
    refresh();
    drawPoke();
    drawHaunt();
    drawChar()
    drawDusk();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // get next frame
}

function refresh() {
    con.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Thank YOU!!!! Im so new at this kinda stuff and this works perfectly! Much appreciated